# How to reconstruct [music store] in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Had just download MS 2012 express and build up MVC4 web sample.
I had problem to load Music Store with 2012 express, it return error about the database crash, can anyone give some explanation on how to change the database stuff.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that i completely understand the question. But I think that what you're looking for is in the file called 'Web.config'.

There is the connection to the database defined. Look there for the following line:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

You can change that to you're database connection.

Now I wrote this I see that it use SQL Server Compact Edition. I don't now if Express edition comes with SQL Server Compact but you can read more about it on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341(v=vs.110).aspx